# "What is the proportion of Spanish speakers in the US?"

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, usage

Do you think this sentence is a correct sentence?

> What is the proportion of Spanish speakers in the US?

I am not used to hearing "proportion" in a question like this. Do you think this sentence is correct?

*Context:* I want to know the proportion of Spanish speakers to the whole population in the US.

Comment: A proportion only makes sense comparing part to the whole. The sentence doesn't make sense as it is.

Comment: The quoted sentence is correct, but your "context sentence" isn't. Have you looked up the word in a dictionary?

Comment: @TypeIA Yes, I have. This is one of the example sentences on Longman Dictionary: *"What’s the proportion of boys to girls in your class?"*

Comment: Normally, you have to be explicit what whole the proportion is in comparison is to, but in this context, the comparison to the whole of the United States is naturally inferred. The sentence is natural.